# How to fix this icon problem in my vscode workspace

Tags: vscode-extensions, material-icons

i am using Material icon theme in vscode, and i have a folder Google_projects in a workspace which use google icon as svg, it works ok. but for another folder google_test in another workspace it is not loading the same icon why?

i was expecting it to show the same icon as of there but no idea why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any conflicting extensions that might interfere with the Material icon theme or extensions related to file icons to see if they are causing the problem.

Clear icon cache, VS Code caches icons for performance reasons. Clearing the icon cache might help if the icons are not displaying correctly. You can do this by restarting VS Code with the --disable-extensions flag or manually deleting the .vscode\iconIndex file in your workspace.